# How can i convert a PIL image to cv2 numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

Im trying to convert a pil image to a numpy array but i want the image to keep it's transperancy, how can i do that?

Iv'e tried using numpy.array()
But it doesnt keep the transperancy

Comment: Kindly share your code and image so we can assist you properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by it doesn't keep its transparency. If you convert a PIL image with transparency using `numpy.array()` it should return a numpy array with shape `width, height, 4` where the 4th channel will represent the alpha channel values. And after whatever processing you need to do, if you convert it back to a PIL image using `Image.fromarray()` and perhaps saving with `Image.save()` you should get back an image with the same transparency. Can't help you much more without seeing an actual snippet of the code and possibly the image.